# Magento 1.9: Favicon switches to a magento symbol in internet explorer

Tags: magento-1.9, favicons, internet-explorer

When I

1. Open internet explorer/Edge
2. Go to a product page
3. Click on one of the product tabs
4. The favicon switches to a Magento symbol

Why is this happening?